# Form model data not running correctly on @yield Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade, laravel-form

all I want is to define the form model on template and then put a yield as the content of form data. But it cannot assign the model data correctly into each field that has been defined.
This is my code:

**template.detail.blade.php**

```
@extends('admin.template.lte.layout.basic')

@section('content-page')
    {!! Form::model($model, ['url' => $formAction]) !!}
        @yield('data-form')
    {!! Form::close() !!}
    @if ($errors->any())
@stop
```

**partial.edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('template.detail')
@section('data-form')
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Dal_Name', 'Alternative Name', ['class' => 'required']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('Dal_Name', null, ['required', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Alternative Name']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Dal_DssID', 'DSS Period', ['class' => 'required']) !!}
        {!! Form::select('Dal_DssID', $dssOptions, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="Dal_Active">
            {!! Form::hidden('Dal_Active', 'N') !!}
            {!! Form::checkbox('Dal_Active', 'Y') !!}
            Active
        </label>
    </div>
@stop
```

**My Controller part:**

```
     /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $this->data['model'] = DssAlternative::find($id);
        $this->data['formAction'] = \Request::current();
        $this->data['dssOptions'] = Dss::lists('Dss_Name', 'Dss_ID');
        return view('partial.edit', $this->data);
    }
```

But the model data does not propagate to form correctly.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work since you are passing the `$model` object to `partial/edit.blade.php` file, and hoping to use it within `template/detail.blade.php`

exactly at this line 
`{!! Form::model($model, ['url' => $formAction]) !!}`

**Solution:**
in `template/detail.blade.php` Take the form model line inside like this:

```
@extends('admin.template.lte.layout.basic')

@section('content-page')
    @yield('data-form')
    @if ($errors->any())
@stop
```

So `partial/edit.blade.php` would be like below:

```
@extends('template.detail')
@section('data-form')
{!! Form::model($model, ['url' => $formAction]) !!}        
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Dal_Name', 'Alternative Name', ['class' => 'required']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('Dal_Name', null, ['required', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Alternative Name']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Dal_DssID', 'DSS Period', ['class' => 'required']) !!}
        {!! Form::select('Dal_DssID', $dssOptions, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="Dal_Active">
            {!! Form::hidden('Dal_Active', 'N') !!}
            {!! Form::checkbox('Dal_Active', 'Y') !!}
            Active
        </label>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

Comment: thanks mohammed, i've try that before, but i want to generalize all the form open and close structure for (insert, update) data. but no chance.. :(

Comment: In this case, just add another @yield for form header :)